# Running bundle from rails shell command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, bundler

I have a Rails 4 application that executes several shell commands and everything works fine, but now I am trying to execute a shell command from it that checks the bundle of a different app or even an engine not used by this app, and all I get is the result as if it was checking its own bundle.

This is probably confusing so let me try to make it clearer:

```
Rails app
  |--operations folder
      |--app1
      |--engine1
      |--app2
```

now the rails app executes a shell command to check the bundle of any of those apps/engines in the operations folder like this:

```
out = %x[cd operations/app1 && bundle list 2>&1]
```

but the result is the list of gems used by the executing Rails app, not the list of gems from app1 that i want to check.

Why is that happening? I've also tried specifying the Gemfile using the `--gemfile=` option to no avail. how can I execute bundle operations on the target app?

The reason for this is that I have built a continuous integration application that tests and builds packages from our other apps and engines and sometimes some of the apps/engines require gems that the CI doesn't have, so running their tests fails and I wanted to make the CI install them before running the tests if it doesn't have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, child processes inherit the environment set up by Bundler.

To suppress this behaviour, call `Bundler.with_clean_env` with a block that contains the commands you want to run in the clean environment:

```
out = Bundler.with_clean_env { %x[cd operations/app1 && bundle list 2>&1] }
```

For more on this, see http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html#Shelling-out